# Get all rows that are not exist in the appropriate table depending on the date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables: TableA and TableB (as in the following picture):
[image]

The result should be as in the following figure:

[image]

What is the best way to get result (as in the table Result) using mssql query?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the logic for the result set?  Don't be shy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the date/value pairs that don't exist.

Generate the list of all date/value pairs using a `cross join`.  Then filter out the ones you don't want:

```
select b.value, d.date
from tableb b cross join
     (select distinct date from tablea a) d
where not exists (select 1 from tablea a where a.date = d.date and a.value = b.value)
```